# Static method in java, can I access in a non-static way to a static method?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I think that there's something wrong in my code, is it the same to call (in `setIstance`) the method `isSameMonth()` in the static way or in a non static way?
The compiler suggest me to change: `timesheet.isSameMonth()` to `Timesheet.isSameMonth()`

I think no, because I want to pass the **local** variable `timesheet`, is it the same thing or should I modify my code?

Timesheet class:

```
static private Timesheet timesheet;

static public Timesheet getIstance()
{
    if (timesheet == null || !Timesheet.isSameMonth())
    {
        timesheet = null;
        timesheet = new Timesheet();
    }
    return timesheet;
}

static public void setIstance(Timesheet timesheet)
{
    if (timesheet != null && timesheet.isSameMonth())
    {
        Timesheet.timesheet = timesheet;
    }
}

public static boolean isSameMonth()
{
    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarNow.setTime( now );
    Date firstDay = timesheet.days[0];
    Calendar calendarFirstDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarFirstDay.setTime( firstDay );
    if (calendarNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) == calendarFirstDay.get(Calendar.MONTH))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

From outside I make this call:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString("timesheet", "");
if (!json.isEmpty())
{
    try
    {
        Timesheet timesheet = Timesheet.getIstance();
        if (timesheet.getDay(0)==null)
        {
            Timesheet.setIstance( gson.fromJson(json, Timesheet.class) );
        }
        refreshWidget(timesheet, context, allWidgetIds, intent.getAction());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG_LOG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer but - the fact that you ask that question should make you think about the design. I see no reason why isSameMonth should be a static method if every usage is connected with the preserved instance.

Comment: isSameMonth was static because I call it in getIstance that is a static method.
But you've right, I can change this in:   
if (timesheet == null || !timesheet.isSameMonth()) and put isSameMonth like non-static.
Your reply is the best answer, thanks :)

Comment: If that is how you feel - done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you ask that question should make you think about the design. I see no reason why isSameMonth should be a static method if every usage is connected with the preserved instance.

Not strictly an answer to the question in the topic, but apparently it helped

Answer (score 2):

It works either way, but the convention is to refer to static methods via the class name :

`Timesheet.isSameMonth()`

This makes it clear to someone who reads your code that you are calling a static method.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no need change your code other than the method calling style `Timesheet.isSameMonth()`.

Since that is a static method, the style of invoking the method by convenience is with Class name, rather than the instance variable.

Otherwise, the people reading your code might thinks that it is a instance method. That is why it is a suggestion by IDE to make everyone life easy.

Answer (score 1):

`timesheet` is not a local variable, it is a static field of the class. And your IDE suggests you to change `timesheet.isSameMonth()` to `Timesheet.isSameMonth()` because that method is static and it's better to access it in that (static) way.

If `timesheet` would not be static, you would have already get another compile error saying that the static `isSameMonth()` cannot access the non-static variable.

Accessing a static method works both way: via the Class name and via an instance reference but the same code will be generated. You can even access the static method even if the reference is `null`:

```
Runtime r = null;
r.getRuntime(); // This works even though r is null
```

Comment: But if I call Timesheet.isSameMonth() Do I use the Gson object that I pass to Timesheet.setIstance( gson.fromJson(json, Timesheet.class) ); ?

Comment: Edited my answer. `timesheet.isSameMonth()` and `Timesheet.isSameMonth()` is the same in generated bytecode.